# Android FaceDetertor vs FaceDetectionListener

Tags: android, real-time, face-detection

What is the difference of this two classes? I want to implement an Application which will track the face in real time preview and then analyse each  frame. Can I use the FaceDetector class for this purpose? Or is it just for the photos that are stored in the gallery?

My Devices is using the version 4.4.2 . But it does not have any support for the FaceDetectionListener class. Maybe it has support for the FaceDetector so that I can implement my application with it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FaceDetector class is very slow. In my experience detecting camera frame have been taking hundreds of ms.
If your device not support FaceDetectionListener you can try to use OpenCV library.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but is it possible to track the face with FaceDetector on the camera preview?

Comment: You can always add Camera.PreviewCallback to your Camera and in onPreviewFrame try to detect faces.

Comment: You might try the new Android face detector API.  This has support for tracking faces in camera preview frames.  Note that this is a different FaceDetector implementation than what was mentioned above, in another package (com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector).  See the tutorial here:  https://developers.google.com/vision/face-tracker-tutorial